# 3D toric code (2D + measurement errors) has higher threshold error rate $p_{\text{th}}$ than 2D?

Tags: error-correction, toric-code, ising-model

I am doing simulations of the toric code using the statistical mapping worked out by [Preskill et al., *Topological Quantum Memory*](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1499754), [[arXiv:quant-ph/0110143](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0110143.pdf)], where we find the phase boundary of an Ising model and use the Nishimori condition to find a crossover that corresponds to the critical error rate $p_\text{th}$ below which quantum error correction works.

However, I find that introducing measurement errors to the system makes $p_\text{th}$ higher, because a 3D Ising model takes higher temperatures for long-range disorder to occur. This makes no sense as measurement errors should impose a more stringent requirement on the fidelity of the qubits. Plotting the phase boundary and the Nishimori condition indeed gives me a higher $p_\text{th}$. Where am I wrong in my thinking?

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say where you're going wrong, but indeed, introducing measurement errors into the system should make $p_{\text{th}}$ lower. One helpful reference might be the following phase diagram computed in this [paper](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.94.012318), which indeed shows a smooth tradeoff between the bit-flip error rate $p$ and the measurement error rate $q$ below which the surface code is in the ordered phase (in the orange). Along $q=0$ you get the usual transition of the 2D RBIM and at $p=q$ the 3D random gauge whatchamacallit transition.
[image]

Comment: That is exactly what you'd expect. But for some reason, something is going wrong. I still use a random bond Ising model with Nishimori condition $\beta = \frac{1}{2}\ln{\left(\frac{1}{p(1-p)}\right)}$, and since the phase boundary shifts to the right for higher dimension, my $p_\text{th}$ goes up. Either I have a severe misunderstanding of how to simulate the system or there is a mistake in my code. The way I see it: in 3D there is more neighbours, so it's harder to turn a spin compared to the 2D case, so it favours order for higher $p$.